# AWS ELB/ALB http/2 pass thru to EC2 instance via http/2 (not http/1.1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, http2

AWS ELB/ALB now supports HTTP/2.

According to the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html):

> Application Load Balancers provide native support for HTTP/2 with
>   HTTPS listeners. You can send up to 128 requests in parallel using one
>   HTTP/2 connection. The load balancer converts these to individual
>   HTTP/1.1 requests and distributes them across the healthy targets in
>   the target group.

My target is an EC2 instance running Apache with HTTP/2 support.  Is it possible to have the ALB connect to the target (EC2 instance) via HTTP/2 and avoid having ALB <--> ec2 connections be via HTTP/1.1?

I did not see any way to do this in the console or documentation.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can connect ALB’s to instance groups. You configure the groups in the last step of creating the ALB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>No, this isn't possible.</strike>

ALB always converts the requests to HTTP/1.1 and this is not a configurable option.

When this question was originally asked, this was not possible.

This has changed.  Application Load Balancers now support back-to-back HTTP/2 (and [gRPC](https://grpc.io/)).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-support-for-end-to-end-http-2-and-grpc/

Comment: I'm hopeful that this will soon change, as HTTP/2 gets more usage and becomes more widespread, ALBs will allow HTTP/2 to be used through the entire connection.

Comment: The advantage of this design is that the parallel requests from a single viewer can be spread out among back-end instances.  You can run your setup with a Network Load Balancer (NLB) if you really want to run your own http/2, but you then lose access to Amazon Certificate Manager certificates, which aren't usable with NLB, and in fact your instances will have to do all the TLS processing themselves, because NLB doesn't do TLS offload.

Comment: Does this still holds ? I have enabled http2 on ALB but when I do  but when I do curl -i domain or curl -i https://domain --http2 it gives me http1.1. is this expected behavior?

Comment: Looks like it may be possible now.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html

Comment: It seems not very practical; a HTTP/1.1 client received a 464 HTTP status and no results when the target group is configured as http2.

Comment: This answer should be updated since it's now possible. See answer by @Sateesh.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, configure the target group to use http2 in the basic config section as shown below.
[image]

Comment: My experience is that although this option is available, it doesn't actually work. I've had no success at all with using HTTP/2 to the target instances. I think the problem might be just the way ALB is doing target healthchecks.

Comment: Same as @user1751825 told - I have http2 enabled on my EC2 nginx, but health-checks never get Healthy if I create a TargetGroup with HTTP2. This is nginx log of that config: 
`int.ip.1 - - [18/Sep/2023:07:18:13 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`
`int.ip.2 - - [18/Sep/2023:07:18:14 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"`
`int.ip.3 - - [18/Sep/2023:07:18:39 +0000] "GET /HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"`
`int.ip.3 - - [18/Sep/2023:07:18:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"`

Ended up using HTTP1.1